# Counting ocurrences of certain words case-insensitive in an XML element

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery, basex

Following is the structure of the XML file -

```
<Datas>
  <Data>
    <Name>Information</Name>
    <Desc>Today is Monday, the starting day of the week.</Desc>
  </Data>
  <Data>
    <Name>Stackoverflow.com</Name>
    <Desc>Yesterday 1200 questions were posted. <b>TODAY</b>, till now 1300 questions are posted. So, today will be an important day for all the senior members.</Desc>
  </Data>
</Datas>
```

In the above XML, I want to count the occurrences of word `today`. This word can be in any format like - `Today`, `today`, `TODAY` or `toDay`. The last one is not correct but in case if user types like this, it shouldnt be missed.

I am using query -

`count(/Datas/Data[contains(translate(Desc,'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXY'), 'TODAY')])`

which is results 2,but there are in all 3 !! How to include all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using BaseX (which you are as I remember), you can use the non-standard [`ft:count`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Full-Text_Module#ft%3acount) which makes life easier a lot.

```
ft:count(//*[text() contains text "today"])
```

Additional benefit is that this query will be able to use the full text index, which will be much faster than tokenizing the document for each query. Remember setting a full text index without capitalization.

Answer (score 2):

This one counts 3:

```
count(/Datas/Data//text()/tokenize(upper-case(.), "[\P{L}]")[. = "TODAY"])
```

It uses [fn:upper-case](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-upper-case) for case normalization, and [fn:tokenize](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-tokenize) to isolate the words. Note that words here are required to be separated by non-letters, which behaves different than the original query using [fn:contains](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery-operators/#func-contains). That might be what you want, though.